# Find the image of the rectangle $0 \lt x \lt 2 , 0 \lt y \lt 1 $ under the mapping $w= z ^{2} $ .

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I try it through points, like as $w=u+iv = x^{2} - y^{2}+ i(2xy) = z^2 $

So, then $x=0,y=0  \implies u=0, v = 0 $

Now with $x = 2 \implies u=4-y^2 , v= 4y \implies u= 4- (\frac{v}{4})^2 $
Also,
$y = 1 \implies u=x^{2} - 1 , v= 2x \implies u=(\frac{v}{2})^{2} - 1 $

But, now, how do I proceed ? How do I find their intersecting region ?

What if find all images of $\{x=0,y=0\},\{x=2,y=0\},\{x=0,y=1\},\{x=2,y=1\} $...

Then it will be a image region with edges  $\{u=0,v=0\}$,$\{u=4,v=0\}$,$\{u=-1,v=0\}$,$\{u=3,v=4\}$ respectively.

But is it right? Because there are much more points either.

Also what will be the curves connecting those points?

Comment: Hint: What is the image of a vertical line segment under the mapping $w=z^2$? What is the image of a a horizontal line segment under the same mapping?

Comment: @Koro please see I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that we will just find image of the edges. The image of other points lying inside the rectangle will automatically lie inside the region formed by image of the edges.

See this figure

[image]

The image of the edges is shown by respective colors.

Comment: Thanks for verifying!

Comment: @Alearner, would you like to accept this answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The image region will be the region bounded by the curves," Real axis connecting the points $\{u=-1,v=0\}$ and $\{u=4, v=0\} $ ,$u= (\frac{v}{2})^{2} - 1 $ connecting the points $\{u=-1,v=0\}$ and $\{u=3, v=4\} $ and $u= 4 -( \frac{v}{4})^{2} $ connecting the points $\{u=3,v=4\}$ and $\{u=4, v=0 \}$".

Comment: Please verify someone.

Comment: Please show working also. The way it is, it doesn't look right.

Comment: @Koro I have already shown the process in question.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Koro thanks,, for the reply!!